# How do I set this big double foreach right?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a foreach in another foreach. The reason for this foreach is that I want to get a multiple array with some IP's I've got and all the dates from the IP's... well this is a little bit complicated.. I need the dates formatted in:

Y-m-d, H:m:s

well this works but the end output from my multiple variable isn't as I expected.

The Output like it is in the first part of the foreach is like this:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ip] => 72.xx.xx.xx
                [all_dates] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:15
                        [1] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:24
                        [2] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:49
                        [3] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:57
                        [4] => 12/Oct/2015:00:30:57

[2] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 85.xx.xxx.xx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 12/Oct/2015:00:32:19
                    [1] => 12/Oct/2015:00:32:33
                    [2] => 12/Oct/2015:00:32:33
                    [3] => 12/Oct/2015:00:34:30
                    [4] => 12/Oct/2015:00:38:59
                    [5] => 12/Oct/2015:00:39:20
                )

        )
```

first of all.. I dont know why [0] => array is empty or better why [1] => array isn't at the [0] place

the seccond thing is that I need all the Dates formated. I did that in the seccond foreach loop but after this the multiple havent got the right output. Well it haven't a real output..

here is my code ( UPDATED ):

```
            $diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
    $ip_with_date = [];
    foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
        $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log | awk '{print $4}'");
        $new_date = str_replace('[', '', $get_dates);
        $array_date = explode("\n", $new_date);
        array_pop($array_date);
        foreach ($array_date as &$dates) {
            $dates[11] = ' ';
            $dates = date('Y-m-d, H:m:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',   $dates)));
        }
    }
    $ip_with_date[] = [
        'ip' => $ip,
        'all_dates' => $array_date
    ];

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($ip_with_date);
    echo "<pre>";
```

Current Output after updated code:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 66.xx.xxx.xx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-10-12, 01:10:36
                    [1] => 2015-10-12, 01:10:46
                    [2] => 2015-10-12, 01:10:06
                )

        )

)
```

The end of the first foreach loop ( end = where the seccond one begins ), gives the output you see above.

But the date isn't formated well at this time. Thats why I have the seccond foreach loop. the

```
$dates[11] = ' ';
```

line, is because the line after has a problem with the 11. character. Thats why I had set it from ':' to ' '

In the point I'm defining the $formated_date variable, the date looks perfect. But of course it doesnt overwrite the date in the multiple array and THIS is my problem.

I really tried my best for this but havent found a solution. The Output at the end should look like this:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ip] => 72.xx.xx.xx
                [all_dates] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2015-10-12 00:30:15
                        [1] => 2015-10-12 00:30:20
                        ...

[1] => Array
        (
            [ip] => 85.xx.xxx.xx
            [all_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2015-10-12 00:30:40
                    [1] => 2015-10-12 00:31:05
                    ...
                )
        )
```

As I said it's a little bit complicated.

---

Solved.
Working code:

```
$diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
        $ip_with_date = [];
        foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
            $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log | awk '{print $4}'");
            $new_date = str_replace('[', '', $get_dates);
            $array_date = explode("\n", $new_date);
            array_pop($array_date);
            foreach ($array_date as &$dates) {
                $dates[11] = ' ';
                $dates = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',   $dates)));

            }
            $ip_with_date[] = [
                'ip' => $ip,
                'all_dates' => $array_date
            ];
        }
```

Comment: `$ip_with_date = [];`

Comment: well, that wasn't helpful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First** question:

defining

```
$ip_with_date[] = [];
```

means - treat `$ip_with_date` as array and add empty array to it. This is your empty array at key `0`

Replace it with:

```
$ip_with_date = []; // no [] here
```

**Second** question:

so you have `$format_date`. And what do you expect? It's just a variable and you do nothing with it. Assign it somehow or do something. But I advise you to do:

```
foreach ($array_date as &$dates) {
            // see this &? This means that changing $dates will affect item in $array_date
    $dates[11] = ' ';
    $dates = date('Y-m-d, H:m:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',   $dates)));
}

// Only after array_dates processing - add array to $ip_with_date
$ip_with_date[] = [
    'ip' => $ip,
    'all_dates' => $array_date
];
```

Comment: thanks for this :) the first part works perfect :). The seccond haven't changed anything :/ the output is still the same. I updated my quesion with my current code

Comment: okay this worked better but now it just gives me the very last array key... like not every IP's with there dates, just the last IP and his dates..

I updated my quesion with my new code and with the new output ( and why does a ',' has appear? )

Comment: Do you understand what happens in your code? `why does a ',' has appear` - do you see `date('Y-m-d, H:m:s'`, there's a comma in it. Wow!

Comment: Why do you add item to `$ip_with_date[]` after `foreach` is over?

Comment: well.. this was my bad.. I havent seen this ' , ' :/   but this doesn't change the fact that it just shows me the very last array key and not all of them

Comment: Once again - why do you add item to `$ip_with_date[]` __after__ `foreach` is over and not on every `foreach` iteration?

Comment: oh yes, I allready fixed that, I put it just befor the end of the foreach.  Okay now all works! Big thanks for this :)

Comment: well I was sitting some time on this problem.. my heat feels like it's just rumbling around haha - thanks anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code

```
 $diff_ips = array_unique($ip_array);
    $ip_with_date = [];
    foreach ($diff_ips as $ip) {
        $get_dates = shell_exec("grep $ip $path" . $inputs['domain'] . ".log |     awk '{print $4}'");
        $new_date = str_replace('[', '', $get_dates);
        $array_date = explode("\n", $new_date);
        array_pop($array_date);

        foreach ($array_date as $dates) {
            $formed_date[] = date('Y-m-d, H:m:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',   $dates)));
        }

        $ip_with_date[] = [
            'ip' => $ip,
            'all_dates' => $formed_date
        ];

    }
```

Comment: the output is like I wanted it but the dates in the output are not real dates.. they just everytime: [0] => 1970-01-01, 00:01:00

Comment: Try strtotime($dates) instead of this strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',   $dates))

Comment: u_mulder has helped me well with this :) my code now is working fine :) thanks anyway :)